# MVC Business Logic + DAL + Mapping ViewModel with EF Model

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, orm, data-access-layer

I'm starting to develop an application, and I want to know the best practices to organize the architecture of the solution.

1. Should I use EF Class Model as my ViewModel?
2. Should I put all my queries and db access in the model? or create a Service to manage all Db concerns ?

I'm using EF with DB First, because the db is already developed.

Thanks!

Comment: There is a code first option for existing databases: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are much more complete descriptions of application architecture out there, but here's the $.25 description.

1. EF Class Models are for your communication with a data store
2. Data Transfer Objects (DTO) are how modules communicate among themselves 
   (WebAPI to MVC, etc.)
3. ViewModels supply the data your UI requires

Look up "Separation of Concerns" as it pertains to application architecture, it can save your butt.  Often, developers will dual-purpose these entities leading to some hilarious results when you find you've painted a corner for yourself.  Not so funny if you are the "painter".

On the other hand, keeping these models requires extra effort and the mappings take CPU cycles.  Here's a concrete example:

WebAPI accesses People entity (EF class) and maps to a PeopleDTO (not all fields, maybe additional information) and returns this to your MVC controller.  MVC controller takes the PeopleDTO and merges it with supporting lookup tables (more WebAPI calls) to create a PeopleVM (ViewModel) that is used by your Razor Page.

In the scenario I just outlined, there are three different types of People object but each could have very different contents dependent on the needs of that "layer".  Lots of tools exist to make the mapping less painful.

Clear?

Comment: Clear! That was my concern, if i waste cycles of cpu mapping dtos to create a VM or send all de EF Model with including child tables to my View.
But this is preety the answer that was looking for.